# Parse DOM in php with CURL

Tags: php, dom, curl

When i use Firebug or chrome inspector on this page http://www.facebook.com/GaryFromCooper?sk=wall (right click inspect element) i could see an hidden input named "link_data".

But when i curl it with php and read the HTML file there is no hidden input...

So i guess this might be in the DOM.

But i couldn't found any way to read the DOM after my curl request, i tried DOM Php function but this doesn't work...

Can someone help me ?

I just want to retrieve the "link_data" value from the http://www.facebook.com/GaryFromCooper?sk=wall page...using curl

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's probably inserted with JavaScript. cURL is just a tool for transfering data, not executing JavaScript :P

Considering this involves Facebook, there's probably a really good reason why you can't just 'scrape' that value.

Comment: i'm not sure it's inserted after, are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

Your better of using the Facebook API to get the data that you need, if anything changes from Facebooks part you wont be affected.

http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: i don't want to use the api, i need to build a "browser-like" comportment.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a DOM node inserted by JS. See this curl [FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Does_curl_support_Javascript_or). Curl doesn't support JavaScript.

Comment: this is usefull to try to parse with DOM php func the html grab with Curl ?

Comment: In simple terms DOM is something used by browsers to render the HTML they receive. So I guess your expectation is incorrect.